# Lendo resultado JSON com PHP

Tags: php, json

Eu tenho o seguinte resultado em JSON e preciso tratar ele com o PHP.

JSON:

```
    {
  "name": "abc",
  "count": 6,
  "frequency": "Manual Crawl",
  "version": 3,
  "newdata": true,
  "lastrunstatus": "success",
  "thisversionstatus": "success",
  "thisversionrun": "Thu Jul 09 2015 11:46:39 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
  "results": {
    "collection2": [
      {
        "property11": {
          "href": "http://click.uol.com.br/?rf=meio-ambiente_home-headline-especiais-2colunas-1_1&u=http://noticias.uol.com.br/meio-ambiente/ultimas-noticias/redacao/2015/07/08/lei-mexicana-faz-com-que-tigres-e-leoes-sejam-vendidos-a-preco-de-banana.htm",
          "text": "Lei mexicana faz com que tigres e leões sejam vendidos a \"preço de banana\""
        }
      },
```

PHP:

```
 <?php
$request = "https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/5bwvka8s?apikey=*****&kimmodify=1";
$response = file_get_contents($request);
$results = json_decode($response, TRUE);

foreach($results['results']['collection2'] as $collection) {
    echo "<a href='" . $collection['property11']['href'] ."'>" . $collection['property11']['text'] . "</a><br >";
}



?>
```

Problema resolvido!

Comment: Poderia postar seu json completo?

Comment: Não devia ser `echo` do `$results` em vez de `$response`?

Comment: Testei aqui e deu na mesma, aparece todos dados do JSON. #@Sergio

Comment: O que dá `var_dump($results);`?

Comment: O collection2 é um vetor, $results['results']['collection2'][0]['property11']['text']

Comment: @GustavoCave coloque na pergunta o resultado do `echo` e também de um `var_dump` da variável `$response`. Assim ajudas nas respostas...

Comment: Consegui através da resposta abaixo do Hiago . Agradeço a todos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No exemplo que você informou o collection2 é um vetor, então como você passou um "indice" que não existe ele não vai trazer o texto.

> Nota: Você também esta imprimindo a váriavel errada, segue abaixo a solução

```
<?php

$request = "https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/5bwvka8s?apikey=****&kimmodify=1";
$response = file_get_contents($request);
$results = json_decode($response, TRUE);


    echo $results ['results']['collection2'][0]['property11']['text'];



?>
```

**O valor do vetor [0] pode conter mais de um resultado, então considere usa um foreach para percorrer todos**

> Exemplo

```
<?php
$request = "https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/5bwvka8s?apikey=****&kimmodify=1";
$response = file_get_contents($request);
$results = json_decode($response, TRUE);

foreach($results['results']['collection2'] as $collection) {
    echo $collection['property11']['text']."<br />";
}
```

Comment: Agradecido Hiago, deu certo.

Answer (score 3):

O problema é que `collection2` vai virar um array (pelo menos no exemplo dessa URL que tu passou)

Então tenta percorrer esse array

Ex.

```
<?php

$result = file_get_contents("https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/5bwvka8s?apikey=****&kimmodify=1");

$json = json_decode($result, true);

foreach($json['results']['collection2'] as $collection) {
    echo $collection['property11']['text'];
    echo "<br>";
}
```